# Hacked or Cracked i lost coins

Tags: blockchain, wallet

Left wallet qt alone for some months, then started it up and during sync coins disappeared?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Balance still not available?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/balance-still-not-available)

Comment: He meant, why bother mining when you can just hack them =(

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that someone took your coins by hacking into your computer and copying your wallet.  However, if this is the case, you should be able to load your wallet and see the out payment transactions.

Alternatively, search your payment address at [BlockChain.Info](http://blockchain.info/)  BlockChain.Info is possibly the best block explorer for bitcoin.  It's a good place to do research.

Comment: After BlockChain it looks like I was not the only one Juked

Comment: Is there anyway to catch the Bugger?

Comment: Nope.  Sorry, but that's the nature of the currency.

Comment: Why Mine? there seems to be an easier way to get Coins!!

Comment: John, I'm not sure I understand that last question.  I'm not talking about mining coins.  I'm providing a way for you to do research on your old wallet.  If the coins were never spent, you still own them.  However, if your balance on all of your accounts is 0, someone has emptied your account.

Comment: I researched the way you helped me and found one tag relating to a court case in Poland and another to Silk Road I think I was hacked and Hence my comment about Hackers seem to get coins Easier than Mining!

Comment: Sorry, Just Peeed Off

Comment: Ok, I understand.  Yes, that's a different question (and one that wouldn't be welcomed on a StackOverflow site.)  However, if you would like to find ways to obtain bitcoins, other than mining, there are many sites that can help.  Feel free to start a newbie post on either Bitcointalk.org or reddit.com/r/bitcoin.  Personally, I prefer BTC Talk.  Regarding the loss of your coins, there is nothing you can do to recover them.  Once they are spent, they are spent.  If you do not know the recipient, there is no way of finding out who they are, unless they've been dumb and published their address.